# invoke jsp from java code and get output

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP page that show data in some formatted way. the browser can call spring showInfo.do and it is forward to that JSP.
i.e.

```
public showInfo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("info.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request,response);
}
```

The output of the JSP is html.

Now I want to save this JSP output manually from my java server side code (not in a servlet context), something like this:

```
void saveInfo() {
params.setParameter("info1", "data");
String responseStr = Invoke("info.jsp", params);
//save responseStr to disk
}
```

I want to be able to save the html page on disk from a service and make it look the same as a user can see it from a browser. So if the server is offline a user can double click on the saved html file and see in his browser the last info.
Any idea how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Oups. The servlet specification requires the servlet container to be able to execute a JSP file. This is commonly done by converting the JSP to plain Java and the generating a servlet class file.

If you are outside of a servlet container you must:
* either fully implement a JSP execution environment, for example by using sources from a servlet container like Tomcat
* or rely on a servlet container to convert the JSP file to a .java or .class servlet and then use the `Servlet` interface methods on it

Alternatively, you could try to use a [headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser) to capture the output of the application.